# sensor_msg_image.h

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to get image information from Image message and make a image data.

I found that there is some guideline to do this by using open cv.

However, I want to create image class defined by myself, which takes image data like matrix format.

I found that message has uint8_t data. how should I convert to image data to double??

Am I understanding image.h header file correctly?

If not, can you give me some comments?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10684/sensor_msg_image.h/) by [ros_beginner](https://answers.ros.org/users/819/ros_beginner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a very `openCV` kinda question, I suggest you look at the very well written documentation given in the wiki http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/index.html. Pay special attention to the [`Mat`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat) data structure.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_beginner](https://answers.ros.org/users/819/ros_beginner/) on 2011-07-21**:
Okay, so what I am thinking is. convert imageMessage into Iplimage format. Then, I want to convert this Iplimage into Mat format. Then, I want to copy this Mat data using memcpy so that I can construct image. Then, I know width and height, but I don't know what is the type of the data Mat data. How should I know the type of Mat data. is it just uint8_t?